# MEAN Stack Data Model array of documents or document of arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I have a problem, deciding how to design my data model for later easy querying and extracting of field values... 
The thing is, I use the MEAN stack and I have two collections in my MongoDB database: FA and FP.

```
var FASchema = new Schema({
    Timestamp: Date,
    ProgBW: Number,
    posFlexPot: Number,
    negFlexPot: Number,
    Leistungsuntergrenze: Number,
    Leistungsobergrenze: Number,
    posGesEnergie: Number,
    negGesEnergie: Number,
    Preissignal: Number,
    Dummy1: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    Dummy2: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    Dummy3: Schema.Types.Mixed
    //same: Dummy: {}

});

var FPSchema = mongoose.schema( {
    _id: { type: String },//mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    Demonstrator: Number,
    erstellt: {type: Date, 'default': Date.now},
    von: Date,
    bis: Date,
    FAs: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "FA"}]    
})
```

First question here, is it possible to automatically create _id fields as Strings, because I heard it should be easier to query for id's as strings later..
Second question: my FP schema contains instances (or rather subdocuments as plain text) inside the field "FAs" (How exactly this is done, is a later topic). My question is, should I draft that field as an array of documents

```
[{FAinstance1.field1value, FAinstance1.field2.value},{FAinstance2.fiel1.value,...}]
```

with lots of FA documents, or should I do something like this (document of documents of arrays:

```
{FA.field1: [valueFA1, valueFA2,..], FA.field2: [value2FA1, value2FA2,..],...}
```

Because for each "FA" document, I later want to extract some values from fields like Timestamp, negGesEnergie, etc. and do this for every FA instance in the list. I extract them either from a mongoDB or directly from a API (e.g POST request). 
Because I want to plot the values later in some chart (written in javascript), where every FA1_instance.x1 value and FA2_instance.x1 value (coming sequentially in the list) represents the numbers on the x-axis, and other fields are the sequence of numbers for the y-values (which are the values of the sequences of FA instances in the list) accordingly.

What would be the easiest data model to extract the values for each FA instance field later on?